# Finding the bounding box around white background with white colour product in Python

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx5BF.jpg)I am trying to find the screen capture by the product in the image and form a bounded box using contour method using `opencv`,  but there is low gradient difference in product color and background, I am not able to do this. Please tell[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLwwX.jpg) me how can I do this?
Also, can I use any object detection method for this case?

[image: Checkout the image here]

Comment: provide some example images to more clarification.

Comment: Hi,Now I added the image

Answer (score 2):

See the snipped included. As your background is white you can find all pixels that are not white using `inRange` function, then find biggest contour from the remaining pixels and finally find the bounding rectangle of the biggest contour.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils

image = cv2.imread(path) # path = path to your file
bin = cv2.inRange(image, (255, 255, 255), (255, 255,255))
cv2.bitwise_not(bin, bin)
cnts = cv2.findContours(bin.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)
rect = cv2.boundingRect(cnts[0])
cv2.rectangle(image, rect, (0,255,0), 1)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering it is working fine for this image, however it would get fail for other background colours, I am facing the issue to find the contours when the colour difference between the background and the product is not signification .

Can you give some suggestions to do the same

Comment: Please post the second image to test.

Comment: Please check the second image with a different background

Comment: Can you help with the new image attached in the question itself